# jQuery each function returns one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id='input'>
    <p>hola</p>
    <p>amigo</p>
</div>
```

Using jquery:

```
$('#input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

Returns like: hola amigo mucho.

Why it doesn't return "hola mucho amigo mucho"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to target the child `p` elements inside the element which is having the id `#input`,

```
$('#input > p').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/956t8/)

Comment: But how could I get each element in div no matter what is this element, div or paragraph?

Comment: Then you should use this selector `$('#input *')` or if you want all the direct children the use `$('#input').children()`

Answer (score 2):

Because in your case :

```
$('#input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

You are accessing id "input" available on page. If there are multiple #input tags(invalid CSS though) then it would pick all of them.
And the content inside #input is treat as one instance, it is not scrolling through the inner tags inside #input tag.

> Solution description : you need to get inside your #input and then
>   apply "each" to get their individual access.

```
$('#input p').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

`#input p` Means every `p` inside `input` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
$('#input p').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#input p').each(function() {
console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you only have 1 `#input` element your `.each()` will get executed only once.

```
$('p').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text() + 'mucho');
});
```

Comment: What if he have `p` tags in other places than in the `input` div?

Comment: @YairNevet i'm working with the democode. Of course Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy has a better answer :) I was too slow for him this time ;)